# Downgrade Angular Directive and use it in AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I am trying to convert AngularJS directives to Angular. Running AngularJS and Angular together using `ngUpgrade`.

I have AngularJS directive as below:

```
angular.directive('countClicks', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.clickCount = 0;
            elem.on('click', function() {
                // Code
            });
        }
    };
});
```

converted to Angular:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[count-click]'
})

export class CountClickDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(public elem: ElementRef) { }
    clickCount = 0;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('count-click', addEventListener('click', function() { 
            console.log('test directive'); 
        }));
    }
}
```

`ngAfterViewInit` is not being called when clicked on the

Downgrade the above migrated directive to AngularJS so it can be used in AngularJS template

```
.directive('countClick', <any>downgradeComponent({
    component: CountClickDirective,
}))
```

AngularJS template:

```
<span countClick ng-click="test()"></span>
```

component.ts:

```
test() {
    return 'something';
}
```

Comment: You could add a wrapper component and downgrade that component afterwards. Take a look at this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16695